# Why WFS request to Geoserver 2.7.1 have multiple responses?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am seeing multiple WFS requests from the OL3-based web-application. Each one has a different id at the end of the url.

```
*service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=layer_name&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3010&BBOX=156543.03392804042,6574807.42497772,176110.91316904553,6594375.304218725,EPSG:3010&**_=1496846692711***
```

Comment: we probably need to see some of the web application code

Comment: Is it the requests that are the issue or the responses​. Is it one request with multiple responses, or multiple requests each with one response?

Comment: @nmtoken Sorry about that, im quite confused at this point. There are multiple requests but only one response with the actual feature. The rest responde with `"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":0,"features":[],"crs":null`

Answer (score 2):

I guess by "ID" you mean the last parameter of the request ( **_ ).
The value *1496846692711* looks like a Unix timestamp - if you convert it, you get a time today afernoon: *Wed, 07 Jun 2017 14:44:52 GMT*

I guess it is appended to the request to avoid server-side caching the response.
Every request has a little difference in the timestamp value, so you'll always get a new response.

Answer (score 0):

This question was, of course, quite hard to answer because of its nature and my lack of knowledge, Greg Z is correct, but I still want to give you the solution to my problem.
Add a primary key metadata table https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html